# Rails permit some_params differs depending on user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails project I have a model with a "status" column/property

And different users can set different status values. 
For example

- not logged in you can create new record, and the status should always be set to 1
- when logged in as user_type1 you can set the status to 2
- when logged in as user_type2 you are allowed to update other attributes of the record, but not the status.

Currently I handle this by having multiple update methods, and different record_params permitting different update attribute lists. But I wonder if this is the right way. Having multiple update methods in the controller is a bit strange. But also permitting all the params all the time, and checking them within the method, I don't like either. How do you handle such situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can change the permitted params based on the type of the user somthing like the below,

```
def update_params
  params.require(:record).permit(whitelisted_params)
end

def whitelisted_params
  if %w[site_visitor user_type1].include?(user.user_type)
    [:status]
  elsif user.user_type == 'user_type2'
    [:permitted_column_1, :permitted_column_2, :permitted_column_3]
  end
end
```

And you said as the site visitor can always set the status as 1 means,

1 --> Merge the status value in the permitted params.

```
record_params.merge(status: 1)
```

2 --> Validating the status in the before_action

Calling this validator in the before_action and respond with error response.

```
before_action: validate_record_update


def validate_record_update
    if %w[site_visitor user_type1].include?(user.user_type)
       valid_status = params[:user][:status] == 1
    elsif user.user_type == 'user_type2'
       valid_status =   params[:user][:status] == 2
    end

   unless valid_status
    # Error response
   end
end
```

3 --> Model level validator

Answer (score 1):

If your application is getting large enough that you're dealing with this problem more often, it may be time to implement a Policy pattern to get more maintainable control of authorization in general, not just strong params.

Take a look through the documentation for the `pundit` gem, which makes policy implementation quite easy and allows you to maintain logic for different parameter permissioning: https://github.com/varvet/pundit#strong-parameters

The link has some great examples for implementing a solution to exactly this situation!